# dynamically add a fragment with custom size

Tags: java, android

I added one fragment to the main activity, however I want that fragment to occupy only the top half of the activity screen. How do I do that?
Main Activity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

    if (fm.findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
        SimpleListFragment list = new SimpleListFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, list).commit();
    }
}
}
```

SimpleListFragment.java:

```
    public class SimpleListFragment extends ListFragmen{

String[] numbers_text = new String[] { "one", "two", "three", "four",
        "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven",
        "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen" };
String[] numbers_digits = new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
        "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15" };

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    //new CustomToast(getActivity(), numbers_digits[(int) id]);
    //ListViewItem item = mItems.get(position);

    // do something
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), numbers_digits[(int) id], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            inflater.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            numbers_text);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
}
```

I modified content_main.xml:

```
    <Relative Layout>

       ...

    <FrameLayout>
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </FrameLayout>
    </Relativelayout>
```

and changed the code to fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frameLayout, list).commit();

however it's giving me an error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nazar.listfragment/com.example.nazar.listfragment.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c006b (com.example.nazar.listfragment:id/frameLayout) for fragment SimpleListFragment{554506b #0 id=0x7f0c006b

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Your fragment is a list, why don't just use a ListView instead?

Regardless of that, to have a fragment only half the size of screen you should add a FrameLayout with the size you desire to your Activity layout, and then insert the fragment on that layout.

```
 fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frameLayout, list).commit();
```